# Integrate XML based spring mvc with java config based spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've already done a simple project on spring mvc framework with XML config file. Now I want to add spring security with java config file in that project. Is it possible to integrate. I've almost spend a whole day searching it on google. I've already read documentation but I didn't get any clue. Can anyone provide me good reference for it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh I fixed it thank you both of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options depending on which is leading, the [XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining-xml-centric) or [Java](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining-java-centric) version. Both of them are quite well documented in the [Spring Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining).

When using XML you can simply add the `@Configuration` annotated class as a bean to the XML configuration like any other bean.

```
<bean class="your.configuration.class.Here" />
```

You have to have `<context:annoation-config />` to have the `@Configuration` class processed.

However if you already have `<context:component-scan />` and the package(s) you are scanning already includes the package that contains the `@Configuration` class you don't need to do anything as it will be detected like any other `@Component`.

If you want you have your `@Configuration` class leading then you can simply import the XML configuration using `@ImportResource`.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("your-configuration-here.xml")
public class SecurityConfig {}
```

Either way will work, which depends on which you want to make the leading configuration standard.